# Creating Element from JQuery Drag and Drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I want to be able to create html elements based on drag and drop functionality. I want to use the Jquery UI Library to do this. The HTML Code is here http://pastebin.com/0cn5FDWr

What I want to do is on the when an item is dropped I want to check which item is being dropped and then append some html elements after the drop div (i.e create an input tag, image etc...).

Not sure how I would do this, if this can be done by calling custom function containing the code then it would be good.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an external function in the drop call that receives the dropped element and based on that you add whatever you want:
Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var $result = $('.result');
    $('.drag').draggable({
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $('.drop').droppable({
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            outputResult(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

    function outputResult(elm) {
        if ($(elm).hasClass('oTextInput')) {
            $result.append('<input type="text" />');
        } else if ($(elm).hasClass('oRadioInput')) {
            $result.append('<input type="radio" />');
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="drag oTextInput">Drag me!</div>
    <div class="drag oRadioInput">Drag me!</div>
    <div class="drag">Drag me!</div>
    <div class="drag">Drag me!</div>
    <div class="drag">Drag me!</div>
    <div class="drag">Drag me!</div>
    <div class="drag">Drag me!</div>
</div>
<div class="drop">drop here!</div>
<div class="output">
    <h2>Results:</h2>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

[Example link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/hs9w9/3/).

Comment: Hi ifaour, thank you very much for this that has worked like a treat.

Answer (score 4):

First you should specify which elements you want the *droppable* to accept. You do this by setting the `accept` option to [`.drag()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-accept).

I've made a two small examples on jsFiddle, the first one using *sortable* and the second using *draggable/droppable*.

- [example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/sY7Vr/2/)
- [example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/sY7Vr/3/)

Comment: Hi Thank you for your quick response. I see what you have done, thank you. I want to add it a element after drop target.Therefore, having the html look like this after the element (say for example it is an input field): <div id="dragItem1">Item1</div><div id="dragItem2">Item2</div><div id="dropable"><p>drop here</p></div><div id="newItem1"><input name="newItem1" type="text" value="New Item"></div>  <<<< The new div and input element is now after the dropable div

Comment: Then I don't think you are looking for a droppable, but a [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid) instead. Dropping a draggable on a droppable doesn't actually do anything to it in the DOM. Let me get back to you with an example.

Comment: @stuxbrux I've added two new examples, and I hope that one of them is what you are looking for! Tell me if you want me to elaborate on any of them.